# How do update a a specific column on some table where a given condition is fulfiled?

Tags: postgresql

I have a schema which contains the schema definition of all table, their name (internal_name) and an defined naming pattern. Each of these tables contains registrations, which utilizes this naming pattern,
the naming pattern is usually a special concatenation of certain column value for a given row.

I am trying to make an update statement which both idenfies which tables need its names generates, and update them aswell.

I have so far come up with this (with some SO poking around)

DROP TRIGGER entry_name ON public.entity;

```
-- Create Trigger functions
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION registration_entry_name() RETURNS trigger AS $registration_entry_name$
    DECLARE
        result text;
    BEGIN
            UPDATE B.internal_name'||_registration||' -- the table the contains each registration
            Set entry_name = 'new_name' -- some new name
            FROM entity as B -- entity being the schema table containig the definitions. 
            WHERE NEW.naming_pattern <> OLD.naming_pattern;  
    END;
$registration_entry_name$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER entry_name BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.entity 
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE registration_entry_name();
```

but I am not able to do this?
I get an error in the string concatenation?
why so?

Comment: I seems like you are looking for dynamic SQL, but it also looks like a very bad idea.

Comment: Can you show some example data of how these tables and their rows would look like? Which SQL statement are you executing, and what do you want the trigger to do in that example then?

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for this.

Comment: Remove as much SQL from your function as possible. Try it first without concatenation to make sure you have the function written correctly. Then add in a variable, etc. Take very small steps.